# Automate click event on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, eventtrigger

I would like to mimic a click event, so Im using Jquery like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#searchResults a:eq(0)').trigger('click'); 

});
```

It doesn't work, meaning nothing happens, [Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVy8r/11/)

I know I can insert some javascript directly in the link like this `onclick="myFunction()"` But I would rather not do it like that. I also tried on mouseenter and other stuff but I can't seem to make it click.

Comment: And what shall the browser do? You defined an click event only. Nothing else.

Comment: You didn't defined any click handler, so obviously nothing happens.

Comment: Ok I see but it has to be possible to automate the click like human behavior..not?

Comment: Sure. Use native HTMLAnchorElement `click` method. `$(a)[0].click()`.

Answer (score 7):

This will work

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#searchResults a:eq(0)')[0].click()
});
```

Comment: You can remove the `:eq(0)` part then: `$('#searchResults a')[0].click()` and should be `$(document)`, there is no document tag in DOM

Comment: Thanks a lot:) This seems to work. Maybe you could explain it a bit...I really would like to understand why this works and the other not..

Comment: @Youss because here you call native click method of DOM node, not jQuery object

Comment: Basically jQuery only confuses things here. In pure JS you would simply do
`document.querySelector('#searchResults a').click();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no click function attached to your link that is the reason why its not working

check jsfiddle demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/PVy8r/17/

```
$('document').ready(function() {

        window.location.href = $('#searchResults a:eq(1)').attr("href");
        return false;

});
```

Comment: Is that really necessary, Im just trying to mimic a mouse click, how would I do that..?

Comment: @Youss - its needed otherwise click event not going to trigger

Comment: Forget about the Jquery part...How would I mimic human behavior click?

Answer (score 0):

To just navigate to the page do this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    window.location.href = $('#searchResults a:eq(0)').attr('href');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PVy8r/15/

Answer (score 0):

anchor tags does not have click events, this will work for you:

```
window.location.href = $('#searchResults a:eq(0)').attr("href");
```

Comment: You mistaken, I said they did not written click in event in the HTML code